# C++/ AVR. Оператор new[](unsignet int) не определён

Tags: c++, c++14

Пишу на С++ программку для AtMega328p. При компиляции получается ошибка - `undefined reference to operator new[](unsigned int)` ругается на строчку `uint8_t* arr = new uint8_t[10];`

Использую gcc, g++ и всё остальное из Atmel Studio
Настройки для стандарты язык с11 и с++14 соответственно.

Что делать? Как лечить?

Сообщения среды:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"D:\Programs\CLion 2019.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Projects\Tests\ModBusRTU\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/MBBuffer.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/MBMemoryStorage.cpp.obj
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/MbFlags.cpp.obj
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/ModbusMemoryBlock.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/ModbusRTU.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.obj
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf
CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/MBBuffer.cpp.obj: In function `ModBus::MBBuffer::MBBuffer(int)':
D:\Projects\Tests\ModBusRTU\src\ModBusRTU/MBBuffer.cpp:9: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/ModBusRTU/ModbusRTU.cpp.obj: In function `ModBus::ModbusRTU::Init(unsigned char, ModBus::BaudRate, unsigned char, ModBus::MbFlags)':
D:\Projects\Tests\ModBusRTU\src\ModBusRTU/ModbusRTU.cpp:18: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.obj: In function `setup()':
D:\Projects\Tests\ModBusRTU\src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf] Error 1
CMakeFiles\ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir\build.make:158: recipe for target 'ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:108: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ControllerTest-atmega328p.elf.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: Вот здесь - https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-c-micro-how - пишут, что для использования Atmel Studio с C++ кое что придется определять самому. Это включает и `operator new`/`operator delete`.

Comment: Странно... Что за  Atmel Studio?

Comment: @AnT, благодарю! Хоть я и пытался гуглить, но на эту информацию ещё не натыкался. Попробую - отпишу.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, 7-я версия. Но я не использую саму студию, а только её toolchain

Comment: а если подключить  <memory>? ...

Comment: @AnT, кстати странно то, что для `int* arr = new int[10]` такой ошибки не возникает. Только для `uintN_t` и других самописных структур и объектов

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
 #include <memory>`

Comment: Тогда может быть дело в чем-то другом...

Comment: @AnT, я тоже так  подумал, что дело в другом, но любопытно в чем...

Comment: какой заголовок включен - cstdint или  stdint.h?

Comment: Можно по ошибке подцепить не тот заголовок. А так же, отсутсвие new и delete, стандарной библиотеки и ABI для микроконтроллерных компиляторов - норма.

Comment: @AnT, сделал как по ссылке и ошибка для `oprerator new(size_t)` пропала. Реализовал `oprerator new[](size_t)` - кажется работает. Нужно будет профилировать как это работать будет...

Comment: @Swift, `<cstdint>` не видит. Видит только `<stdint.h>` и `<stdint-gcc.h>`

Answer (score 0):

В с++ для микроконтроллеров AVR не определены операторы `new`, `new[]`, `delete` и `delete[]` из этого следует, что их нужно определить самому. [Здесь](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-c-micro-how) приведён пример как это сделать проще всего. Не уверен, что моя реализация `delete[]` корректна.

Для себя создал отдельный Global.h и Global.cpp со следующим содержимым:

Global.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLERTEST_GLOBAL_H
#define CONTROLLERTEST_GLOBAL_H    
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
void* operator new(size_t size);    
void* operator new[](size_t size);    
void operator delete(void* ptr);
void operator delete[](void* ptr);    
__extension__ typedef int __guard __attribute__((mode (__DI__)));    
extern "C" int __cxa_guard_acquire(__guard*);
extern "C" void __cxa_guard_release(__guard*);
extern "C" void __cxa_guard_abort(__guard*);    
extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual(void);
#endif //CONTROLLERTEST_GLOBAL_H
```

Global.cpp

```
#include "Global.h"   
void* operator new(size_t size) { return malloc(size); }    
void* operator new[](size_t size) { return malloc(size); }    
void operator delete(void* ptr) { free(ptr); }    
void operator delete[](void* ptr) { free(ptr); }    
int __cxa_guard_acquire(__guard* g) { return !*(char*) (g); }    
void __cxa_guard_release(__guard* g) { *(char*) g = 1; }    
void __cxa_guard_abort(__guard*) {}    
void __cxa_pure_virtual(void) {}
```